# website not loading with www in URL

Tags: wordpress, web, cpanel, cname

I have a wordpress website and that is working fine without `www` in URL. But, when I try to load it with `www` - firefox shows `Server not found` error.

What I have tried:

1. Checked the wordpress General Settings
2. I have `CNAME` record of www.mywebsite.com to mywebsite.com

What could be else possible reason for this outage. Please advise.

Comment: what is the website name

Comment: here's the url : mrviews.com

Answer (score 1):

Make a record of www.yourwebsite.com to yourServerIP

Comment: The DNS server would take minutes to renew the record.you should wait for a moment!